# Evaluation of .dir-locals.el in shell?

Tags: shell, eshell, directory-local-variables

I observed that directory local variables, defined in `.dir-locals.el`, are set for files, dired-buffers, new buffers, but not for `shell` or `eshell` buffers (well, that is also the case for buffers generated with `get-buffer-create` or `generate-new-buffer` and surely a ton of other similar functions).

My question now is, how would I trigger the search and evaluation of `.dir-locals.el`, so I could do this in an around advice? Or can I somehow enable it for `shell` and `shell-command`?

Comment: I've not tried this, but from reading the documentation, you want to look at `shell-dirtrack-mode` (for staying up-to-date on the value of current directory in shell) and its hook functions like `shell-process-popd`, `shell-process-pushd` and `shell-process-cd`.